# Opening current Nuke script into NukeX using Python

Tags: python, nuke

What I am trying to do is to create a Python script that will allow me to create a custom UI tab into Nuke 10.0v3 which will allow me to click on it while I have a file up and it will open that file into NukeX. Below are the two Python scripts that I have created.

1.`menu.py`

```
import nuke
import os
import sys

toolbar = nuke.menu('Nuke')
BMenu = toolbar.addMenu('Nukex')

import switchtonukex
BMenu.addCommand('switchtonukex', 'switchtonukex.main()')
```

2.`switchtonukex.py`

```
import nuke
import os
from glob import glob

def main(node=False):
    if  nuke.message('Nothing selected. Select a node and try again.'):
        nuke.createNode('Blur')

    import subprocess
    nukeProcess = subprocess.Popen(["C:\ProgramFiles\Nuke10.0v3\Nuke10.0.exe", "--nukeassist", "filePath = nuke.getFilename('Set Output Directory')"])
```

Let's say I have `vidfile1` opened up in NUKE Studio and once I click on a node, I will then click on the NukeX toolbar tab I created and this will then open up NukeX and open up the `viffile1`. However I don't want the code to be based on any specific file as I have many that require this process.

The result I get from my script is that when I have a Nuke script open in NUKE Studio, I am able to click on the NukeX tab (in UI) and it will open up NukeX. However it won't load the current onto it.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are passing the **--nukeassist** arg. I think you should be passing the **--nukex** arg [(list of args)](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/getting_started/installation/launching_nuke_win.html)

Also, if this script will be running from within nuke then you can just pass in nuke.root().name() which will return the path to the currently opened file(or "root" if unsaved).

```
nukeProcess = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\Nuke11.3v2\Nuke11.3.exe", "--nukex", nuke.root().name()])
```